# I'm getting to many rows error in a selective SOQL query which is returning more than 2 millions rows. How to get id of this?

Tags: soql

I have an Object with 20 millions row and I have to perform an operation on some selective records..but the selective records count is more than 2 million..and I can't make it more selective because I need all the rows..which is throwing to many rows error...how to get id of this?

Comment: You can use Batch here. Which can process your data easily.

Comment: thanks, but I know this, but my problem is when I clicked the button it will fetch all the records which is more than 2 millions.

Comment: Is your custom button on standard object page or custom VF page?

Comment: Use button to fire batch or queable and check status of said execution. They get result when complete.

Comment: You'll need to use client-side scripting if you *need* more than 50,000 rows in your page. There's several ways to do this, including a poor-man's offset remoteaction method (filter by ID ranges+limits), AJAX Toolkit's QueryResulterator, or other methods. You can never violate the 50,000 row-per-transaction limit.